# Background app to monitor Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, dotnetopenauth

I'm building an aggregator for Twitter and Facebook. Via my website users should be able to grant the app access to their Facebook and Twitter profile.
Then, my C# app will, at regular intervals, check the networks (or stream from) for new posts/likes/tweets related to that user and store the result in a database. I will not use Facebook and Twitter as an identity provider for my website.

Now my question: what library should I use best to accomplish the connection with the social networks? Can I use dotnetopenauth for this? Or are there better solutions?

I should also be able to extend the library and add whatever social network later on.

It is probably a very basic question, but I get confused due to all the possible libraries and options. I tweaked a small and simple OAuth class to connect to Twitter, but this was only capably of OAuth 1.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, DotNetOpenAuth can help you with this.  But you might want to double check the Facebook terms of service, as I thought they forbade any persistence of the data you download from them.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Concerning the tos; I read the following: 2.You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any rights to such data.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to do so with DotNetOpenAuth, I know this because I am working on something similar. Already have it working like a charm with Twitter, working on the Facebook link at the moment. Seems like Facebook is going to give me more trouble then I expected at first.